# Can't write to NSOutput Stream in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, external-accessory, nsoutputstream

Since last week I'm developing an App using Swift. This is my first time working with swift and now I'm struggeling for the first time.
I have to use the ExternalAccessory framework an for that I want to connect to a device and write Data into an NSOutput Stream.
As soon as I try to write data to the stream my app crashes. And as I have to use the lightning port for my external device I can't use any debugging features of xCode. Beacause of that I'm stuck no and I would really appreciate your help...
Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import UIKit
import ExternalAccessory

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSStreamDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
private var inStream: NSInputStream?
private var outStream: NSOutputStream?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func connectToHardware(sender: UIButton) {
    var man: EAAccessoryManager
    man = EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager()
    let accs = man.connectedAccessories

    if (accs.count == 1){
        if let acc = accs.first {
            showDeviceData(acc)
            // ry to connect...
            connectToDevice(acc)

        }else{
            showAlert("Device is nil")
        }
    }else{
        showAlert("0 or too many devices connected...")
    }
}

func connectToDevice(device: EAAccessory){
    let prots = device.protocolStrings
    if prots.count == 1 {
        let session = EASession.init(accessory: device, forProtocol: prots.first!)
        self.outStream = session.outputStream
        self.inStream = session.inputStream

        if self.outStream != nil && self.inStream != nil {
            self.outStream?.delegate = self
            self.outStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
            self.outStream?.open()
            self.inStream?.delegate = self
            self.inStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
            self.inStream?.open()
            // TODO: at some point we have to close the streams...
        }else {
            showAlert("At least one of the streams is nil...")
        }
    }else {
        showAlert("The device has 0 or to many protocols...")
    }
}

final func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
    switch eventCode {
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
        showAlert("Delegate: EndEncountered")
        break;

    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
        showAlert("Delegate: ErrorOccurred: \(aStream.streamError?.description)")
        break;

    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
        showAlert("Delegate: OpenCompleted")
        break;

    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        showAlert("Delegate: HasBytesAvailabel")
        break;

    case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
        showAlert("Delegate: HasSpaceAvailabel")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            if let test = aStream as? NSOutputStream {
                let res = test.write([0], maxLength: 1)
                self.showAlert(String(res) + " Bytes written")
            }else{
                self.showAlert("No OutputStream...")
            }
        })

        break;

    default:
        showAlert("Delegate: Default")
        break;
    }
}

func showDeviceData(device: EAAccessory){
    var msg = "Manufacturer: "
        + device.manufacturer
        + " Name: "
        + device.name
        + " Model number: "
        + device.modelNumber
        + " Serial number: "
        + device.serialNumber
        + " Firmware revision: "
        + device.firmwareRevision
        + " Hardware revision: "
        + device.hardwareRevision
        + " Protocol strings: "

    let prots = device.protocolStrings

    for item in prots{
        msg += " " + item
    }

    showAlert(msg)
}

func showAlert(message: String){
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Message..."
    alert.message = message
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()
}
```

}

And here is the Error Log:

```
Incident Identifier: 9A93439A-CF19-4418-B413-6C75F91E4E16
CrashReporter Key:   fc823ef3cdfaefaca2ed524c6fcc0fe82b5a0d33
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             Test Prototyp [4169]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0BFFBF57-75EA-4EDD-AE2E-B3995E979334/Test Prototyp.app/Test Prototyp
Identifier:          de.test.Test-Prototyp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-18 15:55:46.46 +0100
Launch Time:         2016-01-18 15:55:33.33 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1830b5900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x182723f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1830b5334 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 132
3   UIKit                           0x1886d4c30 +[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenter _addPresenter:] + 224
4   UIKit                           0x1886d3b90 -[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenter _presentAlertControllerAnimated:completion:] + 100
5   UIKit                           0x188220874 -[UIAlertView _showAnimated:] + 260
6   Test Prototyp               0x1000272b8 ViewController.showAlert(String) -> () (ViewController.swift:137)
7   Test Prototyp               0x100026550 ViewController.stream(NSStream, handleEvent : NSStreamEvent) -> () (ViewController.swift:89)
8   Test Prototyp               0x100026920 @objc ViewController.stream(NSStream, handleEvent : NSStreamEvent) -> () (ViewController.swift:0)
9   ExternalAccessory               0x18e12eb40 -[EAOutputStream _streamEventTrigger] + 420
10  CoreFoundation                  0x183071628 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1216
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18306cefc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
12  CoreFoundation                  0x18306c990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
13  CoreFoundation                  0x18306a690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
14  CoreFoundation                  0x182f99680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
15  GraphicsServices                0x1844a8088 GSEventRunModal + 180
16  UIKit                           0x187e10d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
17  Test Prototyp               0x100029ac4 main (AppDelegate.swift:11)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x182b3a8b8 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c58140 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d20ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182bc9dac abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001826fd3f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182719e98 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182724248 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182716f44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182716b10 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182724120 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182f99728 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001844a8088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187e10d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
12  Test Prototyp               0x0000000100029ac4 main (AppDelegate.swift:11)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182b3a8b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c594fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182b1c94c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182b0b7bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c58b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 3:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182722514 object_getClass + 40
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018306e730 __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 104
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182f96574 _CFArrayReplaceValues + 352
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182f963c4 CFArrayAppendValue + 168
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182fb1088 _flattenPlist + 280
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018303743c __CFBinaryPlistWriteOrPresize + 160
6   Foundation                      0x00000001839f0c0c -[NSKeyedArchiver finishEncoding] + 588
7   BaseBoard                       0x00000001845f1b30 _BSCreateDataFromObject + 420
8   BaseBoard                       0x00000001845f1e30 -[NSObject(BaseBoard) bs_secureEncoded] + 16
9   BackBoardServices               0x00000001846333c0 BKSHIDSetKeyCommands + 72
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188066f74 -[UIApplication _updateSerializableKeyCommandsForResponder:] + 532
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187ea26bc -[UIViewController setChildModalViewController:] + 272
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188123214 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 640
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188124f84 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4644
14  UIKit                           0x00000001881279c0 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 472
15  UIKit                           0x0000000187ea1cec -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 184
16  UIKit                           0x00000001886d565c -[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow presentAlertController:animated:completionBlock:] + 512
17  UIKit                           0x00000001886d3c10 -[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenter _presentAlertControllerAnimated:completion:] + 228
18  UIKit                           0x0000000188220874 -[UIAlertView _showAnimated:] + 260
19  Test Prototyp               0x00000001000272b8 ViewController.showAlert(String) -> () (ViewController.swift:138)
20  Test Prototyp               0x00000001000289c4 ViewController.(stream(ViewController) -> (NSStream, handleEvent : NSStreamEvent) -> ()).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift:95)
21  Test Prototyp               0x0000000100028a60 thunk (ViewController.swift:0)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182b09630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182b095f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182b17a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182b17224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c58b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c58368 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183073028 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1fb28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1fa8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c58b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182c58b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d1d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000157b29197
    x4: 0x000000018271ae02   x5: 0x000000016fddf4e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000300
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a1191000  x21: 0x000000016fddf4e0  x22: 0x000000015660b160  x23: 0x00000001a119cb68
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x2d00c1e184f0d870  x26: 0x0000000156606b00  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fddf440   lr: 0x0000000182d20ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fddf420   pc: 0x0000000182c58140 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

If i try to write to the stream without the dispatch_async method the app freezes and i don't get a error log.

Please ask if you need any further information.

Comment: Stop showing `alert()` when you successfully wrote. Because your code should enter again in HasSpaceAvailable, and try to show alert, again, etc.

Comment: Even without the alert() the app is crashing...

Comment: then post the stack trace of the crash without the alert - because the one you posted is within the alert.

Comment: Ok. I'sorry the without the alert the app is not crashing anymore and the bytes get written. Please create an answer to my question and I'll mark its as the right one.